# Copy sublist from list

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i have this full code:

```
program List;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses  System.SysUtils,   
      Generics.Collections;

type   
  TMySubList = TList<Integer>;   
  TMyList = TObjectList<TMySubList>; 

var   
  iIndex1, iIndex2: Integer;   
  MyList: TMyList;   
  MySubList: TMySubList; 

begin

 try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }

    MyList := TMyList.Create;
    try

      for iIndex1 := 1 to 10 do
      begin
        MySubList := TList<Integer>.Create;
        if MyList.Count <> 0 then MySubList :=  MyList.Last;
        MySubList.Add(iIndex1);
        MyList.Add(MySubList);
      end;

      for iIndex1 := 0 to pred(MyList.Count) do
      begin
        for iIndex2 := 0 to pred(MyList[iIndex1].Count) do write(MyList[iIndex1][iindex2]:5);
        writeln;
      end;

    finally
      MyList.Free;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);   
  end;

  Readln;

end.
```

As output i should to have something as:

```
 1                                   // MyList[0]
 1  2                                // MyList[1]
 1  2  3                             // MyList[2]
 1  2  3  4                          // MyList[3]
 1  2  3  4  5                       // MyList[4]
 1  2  3  4  5  6                    // MyList[5]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7                 // MyList[6]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8              // MyList[7]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9           // MyList[8]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[9]
```

But i have this result:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[0]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[1]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[2]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[3]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[4]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[5]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[6]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[7]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[8]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10       // MyList[9]
```

With this error to end: **EInvalidPointer: Invalid Pointer Operation**.
The code is much simple but not understand where i mistake, or what i forget to add to it, for have the output that i want.
Thanks again for who help me to solve this problem, very much

Comment: -1 for Why Doesn't The Codez Work question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of MySubList and then almost always overwriting it with a pointer to an existing list which you then add a new item to.  Instead you need to copy the items individually from the previous list into the new list:

```
  for iIndex1 := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    MySubList := TList<Integer>.Create;
    if MyList.Count <> 0 then begin
      for iIndex2 := 0 to MyList.Last.Count-1 do
        MySubList.Add(MyList.Last[iIndex2]);
    end;
    MySubList.Add(iIndex1);
    MyList.Add(MySubList);
  end;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, this solve the problem but so is all much slow :( Just for to do a example,  if iindex1 need count until to 9000 and sublist has 90 elements, it take something ad 15 seconds or too more. In general i need work with sublist of much thousand elements and so the time is very prohibitive, just idea about as i can solve this problem? Thanks again.

Comment: Marcello.... I find your type of question frustrating.  It's like someone inventing a car and asking a mechanic why it won't run. It's your car. YOu wrote every line. Single step in the debugger and understand what the current code does, or, If it doesn't do what you want, start over, and go line by line, until it does what you want.  Asking why a buggy large block of code doesn't do what you want is asking us to do the fundamental act of thinking-precisely-and-carefully, which is what software development is all about

Comment: Hello Warren, i understand you really. Sincerly i have thinked to solve it using dynamic array and list both, where i can too to do copy without copy single element from list. So i have checked that is much much fast respect to before. The slow is caused from copy of single element from a list o other. Just i wanted know if there was some solution better.  For me not is a problem use array of course, just wanted try to find a solution more flexible and fast. Thanks very much for help. The solution solve the problem in part, but from it i have learned new thing and this helped me much too. :)

Comment: @David: note that `MyList` is a `TObjectList` so the sublists are not leaked.

Comment: @Smasher: only if OwnsObjects is set to true but in this case even that wouldn't help since the list elements kept getting overwritten in code with the same list over and over.  OwnsObjects comes into play when items are deleted from the tObjectList which normally happens when the list itself is freed and therefore cleared first.